# No lockfile creation in NFS setup

Tags: nfs, lock

I recently set up a new fileserver for our research group. The old one was running SuSE linux and, although small harddrives and a slow machine, worked fine. The clients are mostly Gentoo machines mounting the NFS shares via `autofs`. The home directories of the machines are on the fileserver.

The new fileserver is a virtual machine on some department computer running `Debian squeeze`. After setting up (several times) we had major problems with the `rpc.statd` and/or `rpc.lockd` not responding as soon as more than one computer  mounted their home directories. We updated the kernel from `2.6.32` to `3.2` what seemed to fix that issue. However, **it seems as if lockfiles are still not created at all**.

For example, our xdm desktop manager on the clients falls back to creating the `.Xauthority` file somewhere locally in `/tmp` instead of in the home directory on the NFS share. Also, heavy programs that use lock files, like `Firefox, Thunderbird, Libreoffice` etc. are somewhat slow and so is the xdm login.

We use (at least that's what I think) NFS4, which to my knowledge doesn't need `rpc.lockd` and so on anymore. The only error message related to this that I can find since the kernel update is the following:

```
sm-notify[540]: nsm_parse_reply: [0x515dce2e] RPC status 1
```

I can not find out on the internet what that means. The server is (currently) not protected at all, the `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` looks like this

```
RPCNFSDCOUNT=32
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids -p 32767"
NEED_SVCGSSD=
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=
```

and on the clients, the `hosts.allow` contains an entry for `rpcbind` of the server.

I have several questions related to this:

- How can I check, using a small python or bash script, whether lock file creation works normally on NFS shares?
- How do I find out which NFS version a client uses?
- How can I track down NFS errors, when nothing appears in the log files?
- What could be the reason for our problems with the `Xauthority` and the applications mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. xdm creates the `.Xauthority` as root, so the option `no_root_squash` in the NFS exports prevents it from doing so. Removing that option allows the clients to create the `.Xauthority` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think `tcpdump(8)` and `strace(1)` are your friends here.

`tcpdump` can:

- show the NFS protocol version
- tell you who is talking to who (for troubleshooting)
- sometimes also tell you what goes wrong in cases where application log messages are scarce

`strace` tracks system calls and signals, which, when attached to the proper process, such as a shell or `sshd`, could show for instance what `fopen()` calls are attempted, which could hint about the .Xauthority problem.

It has happened to me several times (not with NFS, but with client/server troubleshooting) that the application does not work and either won't say why or say something clever like "unexpected error" in the log files, where a verbose `tcpdump -A` shows the error messages from the server (that the client simply ignored), so `tcpdump` along with `strace` are invaluable when dealing with problems with applications you haven't built yourself.